# Proof explanation of Hall's Marriage Theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I don't understand the last paragraph of this proof.

Why the result of $j+t$ vertices of $W_1$ consisting of these $t$ vertices together with the $j$ vertices removed from $W_1$ has $\color{red}{\textrm{fewer than}}$ $j+t$ neighbors?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $W_1'$ has $j$ vertices and $|N(W_1')|=j$. For contradiction, we have assumed that there is a set $U \subseteq W_1 \setminus W_1'$ with $t$ vertices and whose neighborhood has **size less than** $t$. Thus the neighborhood of $W_1' \cup U$ has size less than $j+t$.

Comment: Since $W_1-W_1'\subset W_1,$ why do we need to construct the contradiction? Can I directly say "by inductive hypothesis $|N(A)|\ge |A|,$ for $A=W_1-W_1'$"?

Comment: That is because in the induction hypothesis our bipartition was $ H=(W,F) $ on which the Hall theorem's condition of $|N(A)| \geq |A| \forall A \subseteq W$ holds. 

But in the last part of the proof our bipartion becomes $K(W_1-W'_1,W_2-W'_2)$ and on the neighborhood set $|N(W_2-W'_2)|$ we are not sure weather the Hall theorem's condition holds.